# On Click of a Button made in one component is not changing value in other component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make Button to Increment a value in React.js to learn communication between two components. One Component is just a Button showing +1 and other component is a Value that will be incremented on Click of that button.

I have written this code but not able to find why value is not being displayed.

Note: I have just one day of experience in React.js.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      var Button = React.createClass({
        render : function(){
          return (
            <button>+1</button>
          )
        }
      });

      var Counter = React.createClass({
        render : function(){
          return (<div>Hello {this.props.updValue}</div>); 
        } 
      }); 

      var App = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function(){
          return {count : 0 };
        },
        increment : function(){
          this.setState({counter:this.state.count + 1});
        },
        render: function(){
          return ( 
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.increment} updValue={this.state.count}/>
                <Counter />
            </div>
            );
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

( https://plnkr.co/edit/SVTfEc5jx5Q15B1c07GB )

EDIT: After learning from Piotr Berebecki's code I have modified existing code to add by the value on which Click has been made.
https://plnkr.co/edit/VL5961FB0mrm4QlxuO9T

Comment: You never actually change the text, so it never changes from +1, you just set state...

Comment: Actually I dont want to change text in Button... I want something that on click of +1 Button , After Hello it should come 1..2...3 and so on...Hope you got me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/NRdAON  and the React code below. 
The problems that I've noticed in your code:

- In the `increment()` function you used
   
  `this.setState({counter:this.state.count + 1});` and it should be `this.setState({count:this.state.count + 1});`
- In the `App` render method you used the `onClick` event. This should be in the render method of the `Button` component itself.
- You also need a prop (which I named for clarity reasons `passClick`) passed from parent (`App`) to a child (`Button`). The `Button` can then use this prop in its `handleClick()` method. This will be then received by the `App` invoking the `increment()` method.

**React code**:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('1. Received click in Button');
    this.props.passClick();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} >+1</button>
    )
  }
});

var Counter = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>Hello {this.props.updValue}</div>);
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  increment: function() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
    console.log('2. Received click in App');

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button passClick={this.increment}/>
        <Counter updValue={this.state.count}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code and also giving me better code in Codepen. It is really helpful.